# What to do with hydration error in Next.js? Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML

Tags: next.js, hydration

So what to do when client has extra, different info than server?

i.e. read something from localStorage, and display it? Of course countent is different. Why this hydration error come?

```
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
```

```js
const getTempUserShortId = () => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return ''
    } else {
        let tempUserShortId = localStorage.getItem('tempUserShortId')
        if (tempUserShortId === null) {
            tempUserShortId = randomString(4)
            localStorage.setItem('tempUserShortId', tempUserShortId)
        }
        return tempUserShortId
    }
}
```

Son what is the fundamental issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

like:

```js
const [tempUserShortId, setTempUserShortId] = useState('')
useEffect(() => setTempUserShortId(getTempUserShortId()), [])
```